# How do I shuffle a VecDeque?

Tags: rust, shuffle, deque

I can shuffle a regular vector quite simply like this:

```
extern crate rand;
use rand::Rng;

fn shuffle(coll: &mut Vec<i32>) {
    rand::thread_rng().shuffle(coll);
}
```

The problem is, my code now requires the use of a `std::collections::VecDeque` instead, which causes this code to not compile.

What's the simplest way of getting around this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Rust 1.48, `VecDeque` supports the [`make_contiguous()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.make_contiguous) method. That method doesn't allocate and has complexity of O(n), like shuffling itself. Therefore you can shuffle a `VecDeque` by calling `make_contiguous()` and then shuffling the returned slice:

```
use rand::prelude::*;
use std::collections::VecDeque;

pub fn shuffle<T>(v: &mut VecDeque<T>, rng: &mut impl Rng) {
    v.make_contiguous().shuffle(rng);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ccf720cd69544bd42cd8d2b00ca3be62)

Historical answer follows below.

---

Unfortunately, the [`rand::Rng::shuffle` method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rand/rand/trait.Rng.html#method.shuffle) is defined to shuffle slices. Due to its own complexity constraints a `VecDeque` cannot store its elements in a slice, so `shuffle` can never be directly invoked on a `VecDeque`.

The real requirement of the `values` argument to `shuffle` algorithm are finite sequence length, O(1) element access, and the ability to swap elements, all of which `VecDeque` fulfills. It would be nice if there were a trait that incorporates these, so that `values` could be generic on that, but there isn't one.

With the current library, you have two options:

- Use `Vec::from(deque)` to copy the `VecDeque` into a temporary `Vec`, shuffle the vector, and return the contents back to `VecDeque`. The complexity of the operation will remain O(n), but it will require a potentially large and costly heap allocation of the temporary vector.
- Implement the shuffle on `VecDeque` yourself. The [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) used by `rand::Rng` is well understood and easy to implement. While in theory the standard library could switch to a different shuffle algorithm, that is not likely to happen in practice.

A generic form of the second option, using a trait to express the len-and-swap requirement, and taking the code of `rand::Rng::shuffle`, could look like this:

```
use std::collections::VecDeque;

// Real requirement for shuffle
trait LenAndSwap {
    fn len(&self) -> usize;
    fn swap(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize);
}

// A copy of an earlier version of rand::Rng::shuffle, with the signature
// modified to accept any type that implements LenAndSwap
fn shuffle(values: &mut impl LenAndSwap, rng: &mut impl rand::Rng) {
    let mut i = values.len();
    while i >= 2 {
        // invariant: elements with index >= i have been locked in place.
        i -= 1;
        // lock element i in place.
        values.swap(i, rng.gen_range(0..=i));
    }
}

// VecDeque trivially fulfills the LenAndSwap requirement, but
// we have to spell it out.
impl<T> LenAndSwap for VecDeque<T> {
    fn len(&self) -> usize {
        self.len()
    }
    fn swap(&mut self, i: usize, j: usize) {
        self.swap(i, j)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: VecDeque<u64> = [1, 2, 3, 4].into_iter().collect();
    shuffle(&mut v, &mut rand::thread_rng());
    println!("{:?}", v);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this very long and detailed explanation!

Comment: Indeed, the `shuffle` argument is quite unfortunate seeing as the contiguity is unused.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Maybe `shuffle` shouldn't be defined on slices, but on a `Shufflable` trait (defined for slice by default) defined the same way as `LenAndSwap` above? That would be backward-compatible with the current definition.

Comment: `make_contiguous` already returns `&mut [T]`, so you can just call `.shuffle` on that. [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e8184aea4c3906b6ae248ea970153d92).

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues Great point, I've now further simplified the code in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `make_contiguous` ([documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.VecDeque.html#method.make_contiguous)) to create a mutable slice that you can then shuffle:

```rust
use rand::prelude::*;
use std::collections::VecDeque;

fn main() {
    let mut deque = VecDeque::new();
    for p in 0..10 {
        deque.push_back(p);
    }
    deque.make_contiguous().shuffle(&mut rand::thread_rng());
    println!("Random deque: {:?}", deque)
}
```

[Playground Link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e7cb864e4421b52b1ef330195696df93) if you want to try it out online.

Answer (score -2):

Shuffle the components of the `VecDeque` separately, starting with [`VecDeque.html::as_mut_slices`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec_deque/struct.VecDeque.html#method.as_mut_slices):

```
use rand::seq::SliceRandom; // 0.6.5;
use std::collections::VecDeque; 

fn shuffle(coll: &mut VecDeque<i32>) {
    let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
    let (a, b) = coll.as_mut_slices();
    a.shuffle(&mut rng);
    b.shuffle(&mut rng);
}
```

As [Lukas Kalbertodt points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41208694/how-do-i-shuffle-a-vecdeque/41209386#comment69617614_41209386), this solution never swaps elements between the two slices so a certain amount of randomization will not happen. Depending on your needs of randomization, this may be unnoticeable or a deal breaker.

Comment: As far as I understand this won't have the same effect, as elements are never swapped between both slices. So it's not a full shuffle and it's different from the "to `Vec`, shuffle, to `VecDeque`" solution...

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt a good point! I guess it depends on the usecase how valid such a randomization would be.